# Read multiple h5 files but there is an os error couldn't find these files

Tags: h5py

When I am trying to read many h5 files in one shoot. There is an OS error states like this:

```
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = '/scratch-lustre/hpc-0227/deepcpgData/c{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13}_*.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

I am sure all of these files exist and files' name corresponded with `c{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13}_*.h5` rightly. I am also using absolute path. My bash script looks like this:

```
data_dir="/scratch-lustre/hpc-0227/deepcpgData"
train_files="$data_dir/c{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13}_*.h5"
```

It works when I use the full name of a single file, for example, `c16_1572864-1605632.h5`. However, I need to read a lot of files. So I have to read them in one round. I have searched many other answers but none of them deal with multiple files and the os error at the same time.

Comment: Does the file opening function say any thing about opening multiple files at once?  Probably not.  Don't try to do something that is not documented!

Comment: @hpaulj , I think the function is `h5_file = h5.File(filename, 'r')`, and the filename is the path I provided before. Otherwise I would not get such error. I am trying to print the value of it now.

Comment: `h5.File` only opens one file at a time.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't want to deviate from the problem but I followed exactly as this link: [link]https://deepcpg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/train.html#configuring-the-keras-backend So I am not sure what exactly is the problem. It suppose work.

Comment: I haven't worked with `keras`.  It may have tools for loading a set of files (a `database`), but those should be documented.  It may for example expect a list of file names, or an name with a wildcard (e.g. the `*` in your name) which is expanded to all matching filenames in a directory.

Comment: @hpauji Thanks for your reply. I am trying to change the source code now. If I have any result, I will update this post.

Comment: That string might work as a directory query ( `ls` or `glob`)

Comment: @HouyiDu, if I understand, you want to train with c1_*.h5 AND c2_*.h5 AND c3_*.h5 , etc. then validate with a different set of files and test with a third set. `h5py.File()` opens one file at a time (doesn't use wildcards). You will have to review the `dcpg_train.py` source code to see how it handles wildcards for file names.